# Help in Solving a Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation $$\left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^{1+\sin(2x)} = 2$$ when $-\pi \le x \le \pi $ .

I have tried to use $\sin (2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$ identity but I this doesn't lead me to a conclusion.

I will appreciate the help.

Comment: **Hint:** $\sin\dfrac\pi4=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\sqrt2^2=2$.

Comment: I appreciate that Lucian. I think, I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)$. It is not easy for a small positive power of this to be $2$.

Comment: So, 

$(\sqrt{2} \sin (x+ \pi/4) )^{1+ \sin 2x} = 2$

Comment: How will I be able to go on from here? I think, we need to make the LHS in the form of $2^x$

Comment: Yes, and since the sine always has absolute value $\le 1$, we need the exponent to be $2$, and $\dots$.

Comment: So, I can say that : $$1 \le \sqrt{2} \sin (x +\pi/4) \le 2 $$

Comment: Okay, so,  maximum possible value of the base of LHS is $\sqrt{2}$ . And for the exponent for LHS, the maximum value is also 2. So, it becomes $$(\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$$ 

Right?

Comment: Check your expression for $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: And that gives us, $$\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} $$ and $$ 1 + \sin (2x) = 2 $$ 

So, I just need to solve this and this shall give me the required value of x. Correct?

Comment: You can say that the absolute value of $\sin x+\cos x$ is between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$. So we need $1+\sin 2x=2$ and $|\sin x+\cos x|=1$. From that you can know everything.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Andre for your help. I appreciate that.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $\displaystyle x+\frac\pi4=y, \sin2x=\sin2\left(y-\frac\pi4\right)=-\sin\left(\frac\pi2-2y\right)=-\cos2y$

$\displaystyle(\cos x+\sin x)^{1+\sin2x}=(\sqrt2\sin y)^{2\sin^2y}=\left((\sqrt2\sin y)^2\right)^{\sin^2y}=(2\sin^2y)^{\sin^2y}$

Now, $\displaystyle0\le\sin^2y\le1$

So, $\displaystyle(2\sin^2y)^{\sin^2y}$ will be $=2$ if $\displaystyle\sin^2y=1\iff\cos y=0\iff y=(2n+1)\frac\pi2$  where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Well, I think for the last statement you made that $\cos^2 y = 0 $ and $\cos^2 y = 1 $ is a little bit doubtful.

Comment: While, if y equals $\cfrac{\pi}{4}$ then, $\cos^2 y \ne 0 $ and $\cos^2 y \ne 1 $.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali, Where is the doubt? We  need $\sin^2y=1$ and $\cos^2y=1$ at the same time, right?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I got it now.. Sorry!

Comment: In the first statement you have written that : $$\sin 2 \left(x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2y \right) $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be just ... $$\sin 2\left( x + \pi/4 \right) = \sin 2y $$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks for your observation.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali, Please find the rectified version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15266/discussion-between-kushashwa-ravi-shrimali-and-lab-bhattacharjee).

Comment: Another way to see that $\sin^2y=1$ is the only solution is to notice that: $(2\sin^2y)^{2\sin^2y}=z^z=2^2,z\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $(\sin x+\cos x)^{1+\sin 2x}=2$ when $−\pi\leq x\leq \pi$.
Let $z=\sin x+\cos x$, then $z^2=1+\sin 2x$. Hence the equation is  equivalent to $z^{z^2}=2$ which has the only possible solution $z=\sqrt{2}$.

Hence $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})=\sqrt{2}$.

Thus $\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})=1$, which implies $x+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence $x=\frac{\pi}4$.

Or using   $z^2=1+\sin 2x$ with $z=\sqrt{2}$ gives  $1+\sin 2x=2$

Hence  $\sin 2x=1$ implies $2x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence $x=\frac{\pi}4$.

Comment: How do you know $z^{z^2}=2$ has the solution $z=\sqrt{2}$? Did you just guess?